# How to pass input text value to another page using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am building a management system in which the admin can select an item from the database table and update the details. To achieve this I have two forms on two pages. The first form is to select the item from table and pass it's ID to the second page where I will use the ID to fetch the details from the table using php. I want to do this with javascript so it will not refresh the page. My question is how to pass this value? I am using the following code, but it is not working.

**HTML**

```
<div id="result"></div>
<form action="update_item.php" id="update" method="post" >           
 <select name="selected" class="form-control" id="myItem" required>
      <option>Select item</option>
          <?php
            <!-- PHP script to select the item -->
          ?>
 </select>                           
 <button id="submit">Select</button>                        
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var chat = $('#myItem').val();

        if(chat=='')
        {
        alert("Please select an item!");
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:"update_item.php",
                data:{
                    data:chat,
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    //alert(msg):
                    $('#result').html(msg);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**
Second page

```
$item_id = $_POST['data']; 
$get_item = "select * from items where item_id='$item_id'";
<--PHP script continues-->
```

Comment: You have two pages and two forms, you wrote: "I want to do this with javascript so it will not refresh the page." Something is missing here. With this you cannot avoid a page reload/post, it will post "selected". You can use cookies or window.localStorage to remember settings or use a query parameter to pass it to next page (ugly) like: ?option=2 Actually, I don't think you need two pages for such simple task.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not changing the page between forms you should be able to just create a variable on the client side that stores the necessary data. Since the second form is loading into the same environment, any variables you have from the first form will still exist.

From your example, I'm guessing chat is the data you're trying to use in the second form. Right now it is local to the click function (once that function completes the variable disappears). You could either move the declaration of that variable into the global scope (outside of document.ready), or use it as intended inside the success callback. (From your example it is unclear what you are trying to do with this data)

Comment: this data is the ID of an item in the table. I will use it on the second page to fetch the item with a similar ID in the table, view it, update and send back to database. My problem is that it's not being passed to the second page

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden field and send this input back to your server:

```
<input type="hidden" name="something" value="<?= $_SERVER['id'] ?>" />
```

And then access it with via:

```
 $_SERVER['id']
```

Comment: Thanks Advocat, but I want to do this with javascript so it will not refresh the page.